# Codesys Error - Function block must be instantiated to be accessed

Tags: libraries, codesys, iec61131-3

In my Codesys 3.5.18 project, I had function blocks MyKeyboard and MyNumberPad declared from a library I had previously created (version 1.1.0) and added to the Library Manager.

```
PROGRAM Dummy
 VAR
  'some other declarations    
     MyKeyboard : ETN_KNP.ControlKeyboard;  
     MyNumberPad : ETN_KNP.ControlNumberPad;
  'some other declartions 
 END_VAR
```

I made some changes to this library, and gave it version 1.1.1. I updated the placeholder version to 1.1.1 in my Library Manager. Now, I am getting an error that the function blocks are not instantiated. They clearly are - the code that did that in the variable declaration part of main project is unchanged, the only change is the new library version.

[image]

[image: compile error]

I tried restarting my laptop and Codesys, hoping the issue is some confusion in the Library Manager / Repository with the new version. Why might this be happening and how can I fix it?

Comment: Are you able to browse to the offending code by double-clicking the error message?  Maybe the problem is caused by something different or laterally related.  It would help to see the code that triggers the error message.

Comment: Thanks Fred! That helped. The issue was inside the library - a variable called in the visu was local to the function block, but not the FB was not instantiated within the library. Writing the variable to a GVL and using the GVL variable solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

As function blocks in codesys are essentially what classes are in other languages, you must call the 'constructor' to initialize an object. In codesys this initialization is done by calling the [FB_Init](https://help.codesys.com/api-content/2/codesys/3.5.17.0/en/_cds_method_fb_init_fb_reinit/#id5) (Function Block Initialize) method.

Codesys implicitly calls the `FB_Init` method one first run with the arguments defined during the declaration, for example:

```pascal
VAR
    fb: MY_FB("arg1", "arg2"); // fb.FB_Init(bInitRetains, bInCopyCode, "arg1", "arg2"); will be called.
    // bInitRetains and bInCopyCode are internal variables used by codesys, don't worry about them.
END_VAR
```

If the `FB_Init` is not explicitly called, then codesys automatically calls it without passing any arguments, in other words the below two declarations are semantically the same to codesys:

```pascal
VAR
    fb1: MY_FB;
    fb2: MY_FB();
END_VAR
```

There's one exception though, you can disable the implicit call to `FB_Init` during declaration by using the [noinit](https://help.codesys.com/api-content/2/codesys/3.5.17.0/en/_cds_pragma_attribute_noinit/) pragma, in which case you need to explicitly call `FB_Init` yourself once during application initialization:

```pascal
VAR
    {attribute 'noinit'}
    fb: MY_FB;

    first_run: BOOL := TRUE;
END_VAR

IF first_run THEN
    first_run := FALSE;
    fb.FB_Init(FALSE, FALSE, "arg1", "arg2")
END_IF
```

Finally, you must ensure that, just like with any function call, the correct number and type of arguments are passed to the `FB_Init` function:

```pascal
VAR
    fb: MY_FB("arg1", "arg2"); // error if MY_FB expects 1 or 3 arguments instead
END_VAR
```